# Exercise 8(a) and 8(b) on p.133 in Section 15 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Is my solution ok?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
The following exercise is Exercise 8(a) and 8(b) on p.133 in Section 15 in this book:

> Exercise 8.
> Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally bounded on $A$ if each $x$ in $A$ has a neighborhood on which $f$ is bounded. Let $\mathcal{F}(A)$ be the set of all functions $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ that are locally bounded on $A$ and continuous on $A$ except on a set of measure zero.
> (a) Show that if $f$ is continuous on $A$, then $f\in\mathcal{F}(A)$.
> (b) Show that if $f$ is in $\mathcal{F}(A)$, then $f$ is bounded on each compact subset of $A$ and the definition of the extended integral $\int_A f$ goes through without change.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the (extended) **integral** of $f$ over $A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense). More generally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on $A$, set $$f_{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\text{ and }f_{-}(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$ We say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense) if both $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ are; and in this case we set $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-},$$ where $\int_A$ denotes the extended integral throughout.

I solved Exercise 8(a) and 8(b).
I guess my solution for Exercise 8(a) is ok.
But I am not sure my solution for Exercise 8(b) is ok or not.

I used the result of Exercise 7 on p.111 to solve Exercise 8(b) above.

> Exercise 7 on p.111:
>
> Prove the following:
>
> **Theorem.** Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $D$ be the set of points of $S$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Let $E$ be the set of points of $\operatorname{Bd}S$ at which the condition $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0$$ fails to hold. Then $\int_S f$ exists if and only if $D$ and $E$ have measure zero.
>
> Proof.
>
> (a) Show that $f_S$ is continuous at each point $x_0\notin D\cup E$.
>
> (b) Let $B$ be the set of isolated points of $S$; then $B\subset E$ because the limit cannot be defined if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $S$. Show that if $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $x_0\notin D\cup (E-B)$.
>
> (c) Show that $B$ is countable.
>
> (d) Complete the proof.

My solution is here:

> (a) Since $f$ is continuous on $A$, $f$ is continuous on $A$ except on $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ has measure zero.
> Let $a\in A$.
> Then, $f$ is continuous at $a$.
> So, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$x\in A\text{ and }||x-a||<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<1.$$
> So, if $x\in A$ and $||x-a||<\delta$, then $|f(x)|<|f(a)|+1.$
> So, $f$ is locally bounded on $A$.
> Therefore $f\in\mathcal{F}(A)$.
> (b) Let $D$ be a compact subset of $A$.
> Since $f\in\mathcal{F}(A)$, $f$ is locally bounded on $A$.
> So, for each $x\in D$, there exist positive real numbers $\delta_x$ and $M_x$ such that $$y\in A\text{ and }||y-x||<\delta_x\implies |f(y)-f(x)|<M_x.$$
> Let $B_x:=\left\{y\in A\mid ||y-x||<\delta_x\right\}.$
> Then, $\bigcup_{x\in D} B_x\supset D.$
> Since $D$ is a compact subset of $A$, there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n\in D$ such that $B_{x_1}\cup\dots\cup B_{x_n}\supset D.$
> Let $M:=\max\left\{|f(x_1)|+M_{x_1},\dots,|f(x_n)|+M_{x_n}\right\}.$
> Then, $$x\in D\implies |f(x)|<M.$$
> So, $f$ is bounded on a compact subset $D$ of $A$.
> Let $D^{'}$ be a compact rectifiable subset of $A$.
> $D^{'}$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> $f:D^{'}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function by the first part of (b) above.
> The set of points of $D^{'}$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous has measure zero since $f\in\mathcal{F}(A)$.
> $\operatorname{Bd}D^{'}$ has measure zero since $D^{'}$ is rectifiable.
> So, by Exercise 7 on p.111, $\int_{D^{'}} f$ exists.
> So, the definition of the extended integral $\int_A f$ goes through without change as follows:
>
> **Definition.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be an element of $\mathcal{F}(A)$. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the (extended) **integral** of $f$ over $A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense). More generally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on $A$, set $$f_{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\text{ and }f_{-}(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$ We say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense) if both $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ are; and in this case we set $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-},$$ where $\int_A$ denotes the extended integral throughout.

Comment: what is your doubt about the proof for 8b?